# Scilab: same colormap in contourf

Tags: scilab, contourf

When the following program is run, It becomes the same figure.
I want the same color-coding.

```
x=-5:0.1:5;
y=-5:0.1:5;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
z1=X.^2+Y.^2-25;
z2=X.^2+Y.^2-50;
clf();
f=gcf();
f.color_map=jetcolormap(32);
subplot(1,2,1);
contourf([],[],z1,32);
subplot(1,2,2);
contourf([],[],z2,32);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do it with `contourf`, but if you can use `surf` instead, I have a suggestion.

Please note, that `surf` generates a 3D plot, but you can rotate it to seem as a 2D plot. And as a surface it has the `cdata_mapping` property, which can be changed from `scaled` to `direct` and scale the color matrix (which defines the color of each facet) according to the actual range used:

```
x=-5:0.1:5;
y=-5:0.1:5;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
z1=X.^2+Y.^2-25;
z2=X.^2+Y.^2-50;

Zmin=min(min(z1),min(z2));    //Absolut minimum of all data sets
Zmax=max(max(z1),max(z2));    //Absolut maximum of all data sets
nc=100;   //number of colors in colormap

clf();
f=gcf();
f.color_map=jetcolormap(nc);
subplot(1,2,1);
surf(X,Y,z1);
h=gce();
cm=h.data.color;   //color matrix
h.data.color=((cm-Zmin)./(Zmax-Zmin)).*(nc-1)+1;   //scale color matrix & convert to color number
h.cdata_mapping="direct";   //change color mapping from 'scaled' to 'direct'
h.color_mode=-1;  //don't draw mesh
a=gca();
a.view="2d";  //2D view instead of 3D
colorbar(Zmin,Zmax);

subplot(1,2,2);
surf(X,Y,z2);
h=gce();
cm=h.data.color;   //color matrix
h.data.color=((cm-Zmin)./(Zmax-Zmin)).*(nc-1)+1;   //scale color matrix & convert to color number
h.cdata_mapping="direct";   //change color mapping from 'scaled' to 'direct'
h.color_mode=-1;  //don't draw mesh
a=gca();
a.view="2d";  //2D view instead of 3D
colorbar(Zmin,Zmax);
```

Is this a solution for you, or you have to use `contourf` in any circumstances?