# How to control the colormap range through iterations in Scilab?

Tags: plot, iteration, scilab, colorbar, colormap

I have a [variable N](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfbBl.jpg), that needs to be plotted at each iteration of my loop using grayplot, which means that at each step I get a new plot of N. However, the variable should always use the same scale (min=0; max=7), and the problem is that I cannot seem to find where I can control the range of the variable being plotted. I know I can set a range for the colorbar, and when I did this I noticed that the colors being plotted do not correspond to the range in the colorbar. I also tried setting data_bounds for X,Y, and Z as seen in the code below, but it does not seem to have any effect either, maybe I applied it badly due to my lack of experience with Scilab (mostly used to using R and ggplot). Is there anyway to atually control the plot range for the colormaps so that a given color means always the same value through all the iteration steps?

```
---- START OF CODE BLOCK ----
figN=scf(1);
clf
grayplot([1:48],[1:48],N(:,:),axesflag=9,frameflag=1,rect=[0,0,50,50],strf="081");
figN.color_map = jetcolormap(64);
figN=get("current_axes");
figN.tight_limits="on";
figN.data_bounds = [0,0,0;50,50,7];
colorbar(min(N(:,:)),max(N(:,:))); //colorbar(0,7);
xtitle("NUTRIENT SPATIAL DYNAMICS","NBY","NBX","Z");
---- END OF CODE BLOCK ----
```

Comment: I don't have time for entire answer, but you should check out `cdata_mapping = direct`, it is also used in other answers on SO. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880074/scilab-same-colormap-in-contourf

Comment: Thanks mate! I'll take a look and try to use cdata_mapping=direct. Cheers.